# Password locking mechanism

Tags: python

I'm trying to lock the user out of the program after they enter so many wrong attempts, just like a normal computer might... but I'm having trouble implementing it into my own code. Is there any way I can implement this into a loop?

```
fails = 0
    password = input("Please enter the passcode for access to the terminal...")
if password == "hello_world":
    print("Access granted...")
elif password != "hello_world":
    print("Wrong password... Please try again.")
    fails = fails+1
elif fails != 5:
    print ("Please try again.")
```

Comment: now you should put this into a cycle.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
fails = 0


user_input = input("Please enter the passcode for access to the terminal : ")

while (user_input != "YourPassword"):
    
    
    fails += 1
    if fails == 5:
        print("To many wrong password, exiting ...")
        exit (1)
    print("Wrong password... Please try again")
    user_input = input("Please enter the passcode for access to the terminal : ")
    
print("Password is correct")
```

Answer (score -1):

You could try the following code.

```
for i in range(5):
    password = input("Please enter the passcode for access to the terminal...")

    if password == "hello_world":
        break
    
    print(f"Wrong passcode, please try again, attempts left: {4 - i}")
```

Now you should compare the password hashes instead of the plain text and use getpass to hide the input.

Answer (score -1):

Please take a look at the following code

```py
fails = 0

while (fails < 5):
    password = input("Please enter password...")
    if password == "hello_world": 
        break
    else:
        print("Wrong password")
    fails += 1
    
if fails == 5:
    print("You have exceed 5 times.")
else:
    print("Access granted")
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use while else for this implementation...

```
fails = 0
while fails<5:
    password = input("Please enter the passcode for access to the terminal...")
    if password == "hello_world":
        break
    else:
        print("Wrong password... Please try again.")
        fails = fails + 1
else:
    print("User Lock")
```